# Interpreting results of K-means after PCA

Tags: clustering, pca, k-means

I have this dataset about an airline company customers with 22 explanatory variables. My goal is to perform some sort of customer segmentation with the k-means algorithm. One problem that I've found is that when applied on the whole dataset, I find it difficult to identify well-separated and balanced group. For this reason, finding some sources online to support this practice, I tried to first apply PCA on the dataset and then the k-means obtaining some good results in terms of clusters.

My question now is, would it be wrong to use this clusters that I found, to compare the differences in the original 22 variables between groups?

For example I have column 'satisfaction', which identify whether or not a customer is satisfied, and I've noticed that the percentage of satisfied customer in each group is very different. Can I try to analyze other variables, like age in each group, to try to explain this difference? Or would it be wrong since the clusters were created using transformed variables and not the original ones?

Comment: If all 22 variables are informative, I'd cluster all 22 variables. PCA reduces information, and there is no guarantee whatsoever that the information you lose is not valuable for clustering. How exactly did you arrive at the impression that the clusters with all 22 variables are no good and those based on PCA are better? Why do you need groups to be balanced and well separated? (Lack of separation on all relevant information is better than separation on information that is not so relevant.)

Comment: @ChristianHennig : There is an argument that says that in higher dimensions, everything is far from everything and thus KMeans will struggle...although 22 isn't very high so it's probably not an issue here 

As regards the original question, I think it's totally legit to perform PCA first, then do KMeans, and then run some sort of explainability/interpretability algorithm which uses the labels as gathered by KMeans and the original 22 features to try to explain/gain intuition for the clusters

I don't necessarily recommend this approach for optimal clustering, but it's legitimate.

Comment: @gazza89 I don't know what "legit" is supposed to mean, I mean, true, you won't go to jail for it. However in an applied situation like this I'd try to find proper reasons why to do something and not something else. I suspect that the information reduction by PCA is not going to help the clustering, and I also think that "clusters look better separated" isn't a very good argument to use it. It is however all dependent on the situation and aim of clustering, so there may be situations where there are good reasons to do this. I'm not claiming it's outright wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In brief, the protocol you are suggesting (PCA followed by k-means) is a manual application of a type of latent class analysis (LCA, also called latent cluster analysis).  Your idea of reducing the number of dimensions prior to forming (unsupervised) clusters is not unreasonable.  That said, there are far more advanced techniques available to do the process directly using latent variables.  (Happy to share more on this as needed.)

Furthermore, the use of the manifest variables (the observed variables you have as opposed to the latent variables imposed by a model or the cluster assignments) to elucidate the meaning/interpretation of the clusters is very common.  In fact, one might argue that this is essential.  The key is that this descriptive analysis of the clusters is not a statistical technique...it is a theoretical technique, and it must draw on the discipline knowledge in which the research question (and resulting data) are situated.

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea of dimensionality reduction, then followed by a clustering algorithm (sometimes referred to as "tandem analysis" in the literature) is something that is commonly done but of course, the clustering problem is more generally seen as a question of whether there is an inherent structure in your data. If K-Means is actually producing some hardly interpretable results, this could be for several reasons; perhaps you might have got outliers in your data set? Especially K-Means is not the most robust clustering algorithm when it comes to outliers (K-Medians is a much better choice and there exist some more involved algorithms out there as well that you could go for). Also PCA is not fully robust to outliers, so I would be quite cautious about this.

Sticking to your original question, the clusters might be "nicely separated" (since that is what K-Means seeks to find) but this is true for the observations once these are projected in PCA space. Moreover, have you used a certain method for obtaining the number of clusters or is this something you know in advance? This can also affect things, since different intrinsic measures of cluster quality (e.g. the average silhouette width) seek to find the number of clusters which yields clusters that are as dense and well-separated as possible, but even then you would need to apply this in the transformed feature space. Of course, as long as you can get some nice interpretable results out of your clustering output, that's all you really need so you may ignore some of these if you feel like it.